# How to test location based iPhone application during development?

Tags: iphone, testing

I am currently developing a location based iPhone application. Is there any way to test the app other than taking the iPhone to different places?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Try this: http://www.vimov.com/isimulate/

> (...) With iSimulate installed on their iPhones however, their multi-touches on the iPhone (which gets interpolated for the larger iPad screen), the movement recorded by the accelerometer, the location and orientation captured by the GPS and Compass, all get wirelessly sent to the iPad Simulator, so they can develop virtually any application they want, before the iPad is itself released!

Answer (score 0):

Even though an answer have long been accepted for this question I'll still chime in with some additional information on the topic.

The kind folks at [FutureTap](http://www.futuretap.com/blog/simulating-core-location/) have mad the FTLocationSimulator available for free at [GitHub](http://github.com/futuretap/FTLocationSimulator). It allows you to prepare a test route using for instance Google Earth, and then have the simulator feed these coordinates to your app.

I've written a [blog post](http://www.infinite-loop.dk/blog/2011/02/testing-location-based-iphone-apps/) about how to use FTLocationSimulator to easily switch between multiple routes during testing of the location features.